# How do I force pip to use existing versions of dependencies

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers

I'm in a `virtualenv` with the line `pytz==2012h` in the `requirements.txt` used by `pip`. When I run `pip install protobuf` it fails and the traceback ends with:

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pytz 2012h (/home/alex/work/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pytz>=2010'))
```

which seems silly, surely `2012h>=2010`? I dived in with `pdb` and eventually reached this:

```
268             if not isinstance(prospective, Version):
269  ->             return False
```

where `prospective` was `<LegacyVersion('2012h')>`. So the version comparison fails (i.e. it decides that the requirement isn't satisfied) because it interprets 2012h as a `LegacyVersion`. Can I get around this? Installing `protobuf` with `--no-deps` doesn't work.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you definitely calling the virtualenv's `pip` binary? What does `$ which pip` return?